# How can I make compilation more quiet by removing "LaTeX Warning" messages from the log?

Tags: warnings, textmate, silence

I am using a the Tufte-\LaTeX class and compiling it in TextMate, which has a nifty LaTeX bundle and latexmk interface. The document is getting long, and I get heaps of these:

```
LaTeX Warning: Marginpar on page 31 moved.
```

This is mostly due to how the footnotes are handled by the class, and thus rarely of interest to me. From time to time, I also get this from my fonts:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/zi4/m/it' undefined
```

As it happens, these issues are (really) trivial to me, but I do care about the other issues that get lost in the huge list of warnings.

**Is there a way to suppress either all or a selection of warnings from my log?** I could not find much on that topic by searching here or elsewhere.

(For the moment, it seems that my only option is to reprogram the TextMate bundle to display warnings, e.g., in minuscule text.)

Comment: You should keep all the warnings in the log because in case of trouble this is the first place you should look at and all the informations, even warnings which might seem negligible, should be there if you want to understand what happened.

Comment: This is very similar to/duplicate of [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25047/5764)

Comment: Hm, that is correct, the `silence` answer over there works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`silence`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package to filter the log. For marginpar warnings, a specific solution is presented in the [`silence` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/silence) (p. 6):

```
% Filter out all marginpar warnings
\usepackage{silence}
  \WarningFilter*{latex}{Marginpar on page \thepage\space moved}
```

If you are using MiKTeX, you can use the `-quiet` flag on the command line to suppress all errors and warnings.

Comment: That works well indeed, I have added my solution to your answer.

Comment: @Fr. I replaced your (working) solution with a more specific one suggested by the package author, hope you don’t mind.