# Disabling "destination with the same identifier" with package silence

Tags: pdftex, compiling, warnings

I'm trying to disable the warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{thm.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored"
```

using the `silence` package as suggested here: [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25047/how-do-i-get-rid-of-particular-pdftex-warning-message)

Example from the link above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{pdftex}{destination with the same}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

The warning is not filtered. Using MiKTeX.

**Edit:** This example is purely illustrative, I have a completely different document that gives me headaches. It is huge, importing maybe 50-100 packages, so it is not feasible to get a MWE from it. And it involves figures, not theorems. What I want is not to alter the document, not to reorder \usepackage commands, but just to disable the warning. For this point the example above is enough.

Is there a way to do this? Either by using silence, something equivalent, or a latex build wrapper.

Comment: Those warning messages come from the engine, not by packages, so `silence` can do nothing with them.

Comment: You better solve the issue by loading `amsthm` between `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

Comment: This message indicates faulty links, so you should better try to correct the code. In most cases (amsthm is a special case) this can be easily done by defining or changing the relevant `\Hcounter` of hyperref.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't silence those warnings with the `silence` package, because they come directly from the `pdftex` engine and are not issued by packages. It's the same behavior as with `Overfull \hbox` warnings, that cannot be silenced.

You solve the issue by changing the loading order of packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}\label{x}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\newpage

\ref{x}

\cref{x}

\end{document}
```

Here's the transcript from the terminal

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bogdanas.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(./bogdanas.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./bogdanas.out) (./bogdanas.out) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/ma
p/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./bogdanas.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2014/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on bogdanas.pdf (2 pages, 30387 bytes).
Transcript written on bogdanas.log.
```

You can also check that the links are correctly formed.

Comment: The code that gives me headaches is completely different, and involves figures, not theorems. It uses maybe 50-100 packages. I cannot get a MWE from that. but the point is illustrated by the example above.

Comment: @DenisBogdanas Difficult to diagnose, without more information.