# "destination with the same identifier" warning with shared counters, cleveref and amsart

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, amsart

The following mwe

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

produces the warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{theorem.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

A similar issue exists on replacing `\newtheorem` with `\declaretheorem` from `thmtools`.
The ordering of the three packages was chosen based on the answer to [Disabling "destination with the same identifier" with package silence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233039/disabling-destination-with-the-same-identifier-with-package-silence), and the `cleveref` manual

What is causing the warning and how do I fix it? Is it possible for this to cause misdirected links in a more non-trivial document? If not, then I'm happy to ignore the warning.

Because of Sigur's comment, I'm adding the versions of the relevant packages. I'm using an updated MikTeX install.

```
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
Package: cleveref 2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
```

Comment: On that post you cited, @egreg says: *You can also check that the links are correctly formed*. So I think that it is OK.

Comment: @Sigur but he says that only after the fix. And in any case, I'm not sure that the same thing applies to this case, since simple reorderings did not fix the issue.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Here using TeXlive 2015 on Linux does not show any problem.

Comment: The difference is in the class used: with `article` we can load `amsthm` after `hyperref`, with `amsart` the code of `amsthm` is already in the class and the package is not loaded.

Comment: @egreg Removed `amsthm` to make the mwe minimal. Is there a better solution than not using `amsart` or ignoring the warnings? Is there a chance of misformed links?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer I gave to [Disabling "destination with the same identifier" with package silence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233039/disabling-destination-with-the-same-identifier-with-package-silence) doesn't apply here, because the `amsart` class disables loading `amsthm` and provides the equivalent code, so it's not possible to apply the method of loading `amsthm` after `hyperref`.

Here's a hack that allows loading `amsthm` in the right position, but that defies the changes `amsart` makes to the standard theorem styles, so this might be rejected if you want to submit the document to the AMS.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

% make amsthm.sty loadable
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsthm.sty\endcsname\relax
% remove the definitions that will be redone by amsthm
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\pushQED\relax
\let\popQED\relax
\let\qedhere\relax
\let\mathqed\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Other hacks are necessary for getting back at least the correct spacings.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

% make amsthm.sty loadable
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsthm.sty\endcsname\relax
% remove the definitions that will be redone by amsthm
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\pushQED\relax
\let\popQED\relax
\let\qedhere\relax
\let\mathqed\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{standard}% name
  {6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}%      Space above
  {6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}%      Space below
  {\itshape}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  { }%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{standard}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\newcommand{\testA}{words words and other words }
\newcommand{\testB}{\testA\testA\testA\testA\testA}

\begin{document}

\testB

\begin{proposition}\label{test}
\testA
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
\testB
\end{proof}

\testB

\begin{proof}
\testB
\end{proof}

\testB

\cref{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I right in understanding that ignoring this warning is safe, in the sense that the links will have the expected destinations?

Comment: @ronno No, the warning means they haven't.

Comment: I've noticed that the above solution causes uneven spacing around theorem environments and proof environments.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, one should also define a theorem style with explicit spacing. But It's piling up hacks, I'm afraid. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea whether its possible to instead hack cleveref to be able to handle amsart's theorem environments without getting confused?  In fact, rather than a hack, such a change could become part of cleveref...