# hyperref and theorems counted by subsection- "pdftex warning (ext4) destination with same identifier"

Tags: hyperref, theorems

I have got some problems with `hyperref` and `theorems` labeled by subsections:
To get the theorems labeled correctly I manually reset the `thm` counter also at the beginning of new sections. 
But then I get problems with `hyperref`. Take for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt] {article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{thm}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \section{One} 
\subsection{Oneone} \label{ss11}
\begin{prop} \label{p1}         
\end{prop}

\subsection{twoone} 
\begin{prop} \label{p2}           
\end{prop}

Ref \ref{p1} and \ref{p2}.
\end{document}
```

This gives the warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{thm.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

I have already browsed the web and found some similar issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233039/disabling-destination-with-the-same-identifier-with-package-silence) but the answer does not apply in my case due to the `\@addtoreset` line.

Note that the problem does not occur if I either remove the `\@addtoreset{thm}{section}` or if there is just one subsection.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the internal counter of hyperref for thm `\theHthm` unique. E.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt] {article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{thm}{section}
\renewcommand\theHthm{\thesection.\thethm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \section{One}
\subsection{Oneone} \label{ss11}
\begin{prop} \label{p1}
\end{prop}

\subsection{twoone}
\begin{prop} \label{p2}
\end{prop}

Ref \ref{p1} and \ref{p2}.
\end{document}
```