# How to get LaTeX to ignore a specific warning?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, warnings

I use `\over` even though it is a bad practice (yes, yes, I know I shouldn't). Whenever I compile a LaTeX file using it, I get the message:

`Foreign command \over; \frac or \genfrac should be used instead.`

Is there a way to get LaTeX to ignore this warning, so that it doesn't appear in the output? I'm using the `amsmath` package, if that's relevant.

Comment: P.S. If there's a way to get the same syntax as `\over` that is considered less "evil," I'd be glad to hear about that as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Two ways: ① unpack `\over` and repeat its definition without `\message`-relevant macros. ② pack `\over` with `\def\message#1{}`.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this properly? I'm relatively new to LaTeX.

Comment: Read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73822/what-is-the-difference-between-over-and-frac and from the three answers it is very clear why \over should be avoided in LaTeX.

Comment: You could use the plain package.

Comment: @R.Schumacher I am aware of all of these reasons. However, I prefer to use `\over` because I find that, for instance, `{ 1 \over 2 }` is *much* more readable than `\frac{1}{2}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo What do you mean by "the plain package"? A link would be helpful.

Comment: The warning indeed comes from the amsmath package.  The \over syntax causes technical difficulties for writers of math packages, so the amsmath folks are venting their frustration by redefining \over to print a message, and then act normal.  The simplest way to stop this warning from appearing in the output is restore the original definition of \over.  Luckily for us, LaTeX saved the original definition of over in \@@over.  So, near the end of your preamble, (in particular, after loading amsmath), just say \makeatletter\let\over\@@over\makeatother

Comment: @Mark thanks! If you post this as an answer (rather than a comment), I can mark the question as solved

Comment: See [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25052/5764)

Comment: @jasonhansel The `plain` package is an old package meant for resurrecting some Plain TeX macros that were not available in LaTeX or had been disabled by LaTeX2e. Mainly for easing porting code from Plain TeX to LaTeX, but it should be avoided. And also using `\over` is not recommended in LaTeX, which is why `amsmath` warns you.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I hope you were not seriously suggesting putting the whole document in that package's `plain` environment? It was more or less a joke package anyway and if intended for use at all, intended for typesetting small fragments of plain text markup within a latex file. apart from anything else it redefines `\item` to match plain's definition so would make all latex lists unusable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning indeed comes from the `amsmath` package.  The `\over` syntax causes technical difficulties for writers of math packages, so the `amsmath` folks are venting their frustration by redefining `\over` to print a message, and then act normal.

The simplest way to stop this warning from appearing in the output is restore the original definition of `\over`. Luckily for us, LaTeX saved the original definition of over in `\@@over`. So, near the end of your preamble, (in particular, after loading `amsmath`), just say

```
\makeatletter
\let\over\@@over
\makeatother
```

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf describes the specific details they are venting about.

Comment: Fixed link: https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf