# beamer, lmodern and \scshape give "Font shape not available" warning

Tags: beamer, fonts, warnings, latin-modern

Using `lmodern` package and `\scshape` in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\frame{\scshape Normal size text}
\end{document}
```

gives:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 5.
```

What is the recommended way to deal with this warning? Silencing it would be ok.

Comment: it's telling you that you don't have sans serif small caps, what is recommended depends mostly on what you want. leave as is, pick a different font that has sans caps and small caps, change the document not to select that, ...

Comment: I don't have the option to change the font shape, it is generated by a package. Tried to silence it but it didn't work. It's annoying to have many warnings of this sort.

Comment: If your goal is to silence the warnings, try `\usepackage{silence} \WarningsOff*`.

Comment: Yes, silencing this way works. How could I silence just this sort of warnings?

Comment: You do have the option to change the font shape. If you delete `\scshape` then it will not try to use that font shape.

Comment: `\let\scshape\relax` would for example work.

Comment: @DenisBogdanas: See the end of [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25052/5764)

Comment: instead of lmodern load `\usepackage{libertine}`

Answer (score 4):

I managed to filter the warnings, with either

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape}
```

or, if `silence` package have to be loaded in safe mode:

```
\usepackage[safe]{silence}
\WarningFilter*{latexfont}{Font}
```