# (??) when citing, error message during LaTeX typesetting!

Tags: errors, citing, bbl

I use `\cite` commands and recently, only from a certain line in my document, the references are written as (?) but the full references are found at the end of my document like previously..

Error message when running Latex typesetting:

```
(./Ocean_Sciences.bbl [3 ./Ocean_Sciences.bbl:42: pdfTeX error (ext4):
\pdfendlink ended up in different  nesting level than \pdfstartlink.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi  l.42 
       ./Ocean_Sciences.bbl:42:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced ! Transcript written on Ocean_Sciences.log.
```

So it has something to do with my `bbl` file?

Comment: Delete *all* intermediate files and process the file again. Check you don't have dumb mistakes in your `.bib` file (the programs reading those are quite fragile, and get easily derailed by unexpected characters, syntax errors, or duplicate entries).

Comment: The standard answer for your symptom normally is [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), though it is a bit weird that you only get question marks in the citations while the bibliography works. Further information about what packages/techniques you are using to get citations and your bibliography would be greatly appreciated. An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would be superb, I suspect you can even find the problem yourself while comping up with one.

Comment: See also [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25047/35864), [LaTeX not compiling properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765229)