# texlive 2016 hyperref/cleverref incompatibility

Tags: hyperref, texlive, cleveref, amsthm

I almost always use [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com/) for my LaTeX needs, but I recently began work on a relatively large document, and so I figured I would give a local TeX distribution a try to see if I could speed up the compile times.  I thus decided to download [MikTeX 2.9.5997 64-bit for Windows](http://miktex.org/download) and used [TeXstudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) as my front end.  I then simply copy and pasted my project into TeXstudio, expecting it to run, but instead I found a plethora of errors.

I tried downloading [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) instead, as well as [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), and tried all four combinations (both front-ends with both distributions), and in all cases, I found the same exact errors.

I then proceeded to simply cut-down my file to try to isolate the problem.  What follows is the resulting MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is my theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

This throws about 6 errors, the first being "No counter 't' defined", the second being "Missing number treated as 0", and the remaining being "perhaps a missing \item", all of which are thrown on the `\begin{thm}` line except the last error which is thrown on the `\end{thm}` line.  Furthermore, (I) this document compiles fine in ShareLaTeX, and (II) if you remove any of

1. `\usepackage{hyperref}`,
2. `\usepackage{cleveref}`, or
3. `[equation]` in the `\newtheorem` line,

   it will likewise compile just fine.

What on earth could be causing such an error?

**UPDATE 1**:  It also complies fine if you remove `\usepackage{amsthm}`.  I also confirmed that the problem still occurs if you use a different counter.

**UPDATE 2**:  I confirmed that this *does* compile correctly with TeX Live 2015.  After checking the respective CTAN pages, it seems as if the only package being used here which has been updated since 2015 is `hyperref`.  I suppose this means that a bug must have been introduced into the `hyperref` package?

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.6.18)  19 JUN 2016 00:29
entering extended mode
**./stackexchange.tex
(stackexchange.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\thm@style=\toks14
\thm@bodyfont=\toks15
\thm@headfont=\toks16
\thm@notefont=\toks17
\thm@headpunct=\toks18
\thm@preskip=\skip43
\thm@postskip=\skip44
\thm@headsep=\skip45
\dth@everypar=\toks19
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2016/05/21 v6.83p Hypertext links for LaTeX

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/05/16 v1.17 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks20
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen103
\Hy@linkcounter=\count87
\Hy@pagecounter=\count88

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count89

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4486.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4491.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4494.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4501.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4735.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count90

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5088.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen104
\Fld@menulength=\count91
\Field@Width=\dimen105
\Fld@charsize=\dimen106
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6342.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6350.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6357.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6372.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6412.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6416.
\Hy@abspage=\count92
\c@Item=\count93
\c@Hfootnote=\count94
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count95
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count96

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip46
)
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\cleveref\cleveref.sty"
Package: cleveref 2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `hyperref' support loaded on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cref on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cref on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \crefrange on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Crefrange on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpageref on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpageref on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpagerefrange on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpagerefrange on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcref on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcpageref on input line 2230.
Package cleveref Info: `amsthm' support loaded on input line 2858.
)
No file stackexchange.aux.
\openout1 = `stackexchange.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box26
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 9.
("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

("D:\Program Files\TeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count97
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 9.
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `stackexchange.out'.



! LaTeX Error: No counter 't' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{thm}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@t 
l.11 \begin{thm}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{thm}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{thm}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{thm}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \end{thm}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 15.
[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 15.
 (stackexchange.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 15.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 15.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `stackexchange.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `stackexchange.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 15.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5799 strings out of 493335
 96908 string characters out of 3142235
 198351 words of memory out of 3000000
 9356 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4294 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,4n,21p,188b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/Program Files/TeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on stackexchange.pdf (1 page, 14559 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: What do you mean with`[equation]`? Normally  a counter in this position is for a shared counter.  Equations and theorems sharing the same counter seems strange. That said, it compiles if `cleveref` is loaded *after* `\newtheorem…`.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  In the document, everything shares the same counter---theorems, lemma, equations, propositions, etc..  This perhaps isn't the most logical choice, but I chose to number things this way because it makes things easiest to find---if you're looking for Theorem 5.6.24 and you see  Equation 5.6.37, you know you need to look back/up..  In any case, even if I were to change this design decision, presumably the problem would remain.  I can't imagine that changing the counter here would fix things.  Then again, I couldn't imagine this happening in the first place . . .

Comment: @Bernard That it compiles when `cleveref` is loaded after `\newtheorem` is a bit odd--- the documentation explicitly says to load `cleveref` *before* all `\newtheorems`s.  I'm guessing, while it may compile, you would lose the `cleveref` functionality?

Comment: As I said, load `cleveref` at the end, and it will compile fine. But in this case, cleveref will be of no use: it is supposed to know (and print) which type of structure a given counter is associated?. How do you want it to find its way if the same counter can correspond to an equation as well as a theorem or a corollary?

Comment: Your last comment was posted while I was writing mine. To answer your question, you'll lose the cleveref functionality *by design*, unless you find a way to explain to cleveref which structure corresponds to such and such value of the counter.

Comment: your MWE compiles fine for me (miktex2.9)

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know the exact version (that is 2.9.ABCD)?  Maybe rolling back to an earlier build of 2.9 would fix the problem?

@Bernard, you said it failed to compile for you as well, yes?  What version of MikTeX / TeX Live are you using?

Comment: I use MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit. It was re-installed a few months ago (2-3), and it's updated regularly.

Comment: Are you sure these are errors, or are they just warnings? Related: [How do I get rid of particular pdftex warning message?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25047/5764) The order in which you load [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) is important.

Comment: @Werner I tried compiling the document in the related question you linked and I did not get the same warnings, but in fact the same errors I received as before.  Moreover, I tried changing the order of the packages as suggested in the accepted answer there and it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added =)

Comment: @Bernard: I can reproduce the problem, both with miktex and texlive 2016. But I'm not sure who is to blame. Obviously both hyperref and cleveref are trying to patch thm.  If you really don't get it with the example in the question: Can you add \tracingmacros=1 before begin{thm} and sent me the log?

Comment: Compiles using `(TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.7.8) `

Comment: @Bernard -- the use of `[equation]` so that everything shares the same numbering scheme is an accepted (and sometimes recommended) numbering mechanism, though rather rare.

Comment: granted i'm using an older version of tex live, but this example has no conceptual errors, and works as presented.  the problem is almost certainly the result of an update to one of the packages (not amsthm, which hasn't been updated for years); many updates have been made with tex live 2016.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just checked the CTAN page for `cleveref` and it seems as if the most recent version of it is dated as 28 December 2013.  Does this necessarily mean that the problem is with `hyperref`, in particular, an update made to `hyperref` made sometime between the release of TeX Live 2015 and 2016?  Do you know if there is a way to use older versions of a package to test this?

Comment: there *is* an archive of "previous" versions; see [Historical, stable version archive of packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/579).  if you retrieve an older version (without replacing the *current* version), you can put it into yuor working directory, and that one will be used.  (you can delete it or rename it after testing.) but i'm not sure how many other packages are loaded by `hyperref`; you should be careful about that too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is fixed in hyperref release 6.83q 2016-06-24

---

The change to hyperref was to fix this issue

https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/11

which I have just re-opened, pointing here.

I will update hyperref to address this (somehow:-) but meanwhile, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\let\xx@thm\@thm
\AtBeginDocument{\let\@thm\xx@thm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\begin{thm}
This is my theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

You do however get the warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
  (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

But that warning was also issued with the texlive 2015 hyperref.

Which was the issue that github issue #11 was trying to fix.

For now I have just reopened the issue, will look later for a safe fix, if anyone has any suggestions feel free to comment here or on github:-)

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!  In fact, had you not mentioned the warning, I would not have even noticed---Texmaker doesn't `report' it and I had to look in the log file itself to find it.  I actually never noticed this before, and maybe ShareLaTeX has been doing it too all along?  This isn't really related to the original question, but why does Texmaker not list this along with other warnings (e.g. an overfull hbox warning)?

Comment: @JonathanGleason You'd have to ask the texmaker devs about that:-) probably because the warning comes from pdftex internals, not from hyperref and unlike a latex package warning it doesn't force a newline, I lied a bit above the actual log looks like `[1pdfTeX warning...` that is, it comes in the _middle_ of the `[1]` denoting that page 1 is being shipped out.