# Theorem does not work after MikTeX update; no counter defined

Tags: hyperref, theorems, counters, cleveref

The following stopped working after I updated MikTeX today:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{cleveref}

 \newtheorem{definition_}[equation]{Definition}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{definition_}[Something]
 Something
 \end{definition_}
 \end{document}
```

The error is

```
No counter 'd' defined. \begin{definition_}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this is a bug somewhere? The document builds fine if I remove any of the three `\usepackages`, or remove `[equation]`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315462/texlive-2016-hyperref-cleverref-incompatibility.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is exactly my problem; this is a duplicate. Thank you.