# Remove dot after theorem with amsthm and hyperref

Tags: theorems, punctuation, amsthm

I would like to know how to remove the dot that `amsthm` adds after the number of the theorem (it gives **Theorem 1.1.** instead of **Theorem 1.1** ).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}
Let ...
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}
Let ...
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

It turns out that if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is not included, then adding

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

fixes the problem, but when it is then the problem is still there.

I need to use `amsthm` but I don't want the dot to appear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already tried the solution given there and it didn't work @samcarter

Comment: The solution given there doesn't fix the problem here. Adding `hyperref` makes that solution not fix the problem @StefanPinnow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}
Let ...
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

Including `hyperref` you have to use the patch at the beginning of the document, see [texlive 2016 hyperref/cleverref incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315462/texlive-2016-hyperref-cleverref-incompatibility)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}
Let ...
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You were completely right. The MWE I wrote was fixed with the code you wrote, but in my thesis (where I have this problem) it wasn't fixed. I have been trying to see what is different and I have just found it: if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is added (I have this package in my thesis) then the problem is still there. How could I fix it? Thanks for your quick answer, by the way.

Comment: @Minkowski Just a guess: by changing the order the packages are loaded. But if you want a real answer, make a MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: I have just changed the question and the MWE. [The 11th Doctor is actually _my_  Doctor, but the 12th is also fantastic]

Comment: @Minkowski For the 11th Doctor you get this new version of my anwser :)

Comment: Geronimo! You nailed it! Now it works perfecty. I have to tell you that I have been searching the solution to this problem for months. Thank you very much  @samcarter .

Comment: @Minkowski You're welcome! A simple question that turned out to be more interesting than I first thought!