# remove the dot after Theorem while using the cleveref package

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, amsthm

I want to remove the dot after the numbering of theorems, definitions etc. within the `amsthm` package. (So I get **Theorem 1.1** instead of **Theorem 1.1.**) (EDIT: I want to remove the dot from the theorems themselfs)
I am using both the `hyperref` and the `cleveref` packages, both of which pose problems.
I already found a solution to the `hyperref` package here [Remove dot after theorem with amsthm and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338209/remove-dot-after-theorem-with-amsthm-and-hyperref), but when using the `cleveref` package, the dot reappears.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\begin{theorem}
    World
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

which outputs
[image]
How can i remove that dot?

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the references or also from the theorem itself?

Comment: @Bernard from the Theorem itself

Comment: Well, this is quite easy with the `ntheorem` package:  you just code `\theorem{separator{}` before declaring your theorems, definitions, &c.

Comment: @Bernard the `ntheorem` package gives me an error: `! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.`

Comment: Did you load both amsthm and ntheorem?

Comment: yes, I did. When I only use the `ntheorem` package, I don't even need the `\theorem{separator{}}`. However I then run into difficulties, since I use quite some features from `amsthm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cleveref`](//ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) changes `\@thm` making the linked solution not work anymore. Adding `\tracingpatches` before you attempt to patch `\@thm` will reveal that the "search pattern [is] not found in [the] replacement text."

The following updates the patches when using `cleveref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% Patch to accommodate for \begin{theorem}[...]
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\cref@thmoptarg}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}}
% Patch to accommodate \begin{theorem} (without an optional argument)
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\cref@thmnoarg}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\begin{theorem}
World
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

My (rough) process for identifying the updates patches:

- Add a `\typeout{success}` and `\typeout{failure}` to the `<success>` and `<failure>` in the patch:

  ```
  \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  ```

  This will allow you to examine the `.log` and see whether the patch worked or failed.
- If it failed, add `\tracingpatches` before the patches are made and see what the `.log` outputs. Is the search pattern still the same? Did the macro change?
- Look at the actual macro being patched to see what it is defined as using `\show`. In my case, `\show\@thm`.
- From there, follow any subsidiary macro definitions to see find out where the changes should be applied to your original `\xpatchcmd`.

  In this case, `\@thm` conditioned on an optional argument, and it was clearly introduced by `cleveref` since the two subsidiary macros were `\cref@thmoptarg` and `\cref@thmnoarg`.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to explain better your patches, please? In meantime +1.

Comment: works like a charm, huge thank you

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've added some more detail.

Comment: @Werner I'm a scarce user....:-( Thank you very very...much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `amsthm`, you would need to define a new theorem style:

```
\newtheoremstyle{nodot}
  {}{} % Default space above and below
  {\itshape}{} % italic body unindented
  {\bfseries}{} % bold theorem head, no dot after
  { }{} % normal space between theorem head and body, default head spec
```

The full details can be had by typing `texdoc amsthm` at a command line.